# TweenMax does not animate (GSAP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

If I wrote the script code in my html file, the animation works.  But if the animation code is  in a js file, it just didn't work.
here is my animation code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        var cow = document.getElementsByTagName("cow");

        TweenMax.to(cow, 2, {top:"1200px",ease: Back.easeOut});
}

)})
```

and here is what in the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'cow.css'/>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js">       
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src = 'showanimationcow.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
   <img id = "cow" src ="http://cdn.snappages.com/adwr7m/theme/338649/images/
   13179326871659847108SimpleCowArt.svg.hi_1393086508.png">
</body>
```

I will very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `document.getElementById("cow")`

Also, it's not necessary to call `$(document).ready` and `$(window).on("load",function() {` the same time.

Comment: Good answer except It is perfectly acceptable to call a window load event within a `ready()` event. The `ready()` event checks whether the DOM is ready. The window load event is checking if the window is loaded so you know the `<img>` is fully loaded before animating it. The window load event makes sure images, style-sheets, javascript files, fonts, links, and other external assets are loaded. Sometimes the window event fires before the DOM is ready or vice versa due to waiting on the server, asset loading, etc..